# jboss-tools html editor: remove trailing spaces

Tags: jboss-tools, eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
Version: Oxygen Release (v4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Preferences of AnyEdit Tools (v2.7.0.201705171641):
- (x) Remove trailing  whitespaces
- (x) Convert tabs <-> spaces
-- (x) Tabs to spaces

HTML-files are opened with: JBoss Tools HTML Editor

While saving file, tabs aren't replaced and trailing spaces are still there

But if I open the HTM-files with "Text Editor" or "HTML Editor", the changes are made correctly.

Is there a setting in JBoss Tools I didn't saw? Or do they have problems with other Tools?